# Tensorflow Data Pipeline: Read text files from sub-directories for Seq2Seq Models

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, seq2seq

I am trying to create a data pipeline using Tensorflow's `text_dataset_from_directory` method for training a seq-to-seq model. The folder structure as below:

```
BBC News Articles
   |_ News Articles
      |_Business
          |_001.txt, 002.txt
      |_Sports
          |_001.txt, 002.txt
   |_Summaries
      |_Business
          |_001.txt, 002.txt
      |_Sports
          |_ 001.txt, 002.txt
```

How do I create a tensorflow pipeline that reads the text files where the data is read from the folders. `News Articles` are is the input and `Summaries` is the target. I have tried the following but it doesn't maintain the index of the inputs and the target

```
articles_path = "./BBC News Summary/News Articles/"
summary_path = "./BBC News Summary/Summaries/"

batch_size = 32
seed = 42

articles_data = utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
                    articles_path,
                    labels=None,
                    batch_size = batch_size,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    subset='training',
                    seed=seed)

summary_data = utils.text_dataset_from_directory(
                    summary_path,
                    labels=None,
                    batch_size = batch_size,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    subset='training',
                    seed=seed)
```

If I just pass `"./BBC News Articles"` as the path then it reads all the files under one training set and doesn't create labels which would be the **Summaries**. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.